# Solve trigonometric inequality $\cos x \geq \sin^2 x - \cos^2 x $

Tags: trigonometry

Solve trigonometric inequality $$\cos x  \geq \sin^2 x - \cos^2 x $$
My incorrect solution: 
$$\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x \geq -\cos x $$
$$\cos 2x \geq \cos (\pi - x) $$
which means:
$$ 2x \geq -(\pi + x)$$ 
$$ x \geq -\pi $$ 
Which is wrong.

And
$$ 2x \leq  2\pi + (\pi - x)$$ 
$$ x \leq \pi$$

Comment: why did you change cos2x to 2x? That's the mistake

Comment: How did you jump from the second to third inequality?

Comment: $-\cos{x} = cos(\pi+x)\quad or \quad cos(\pi-x)$

Comment: Surely you must have been given a bound for $x$? Also draw the graph of $\cos(2x)$ and $-\cos(x)$

Comment: “$\cos\alpha > \cos\beta$” is not equivalent to “$\alpha>\beta$”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments have outlined what you are doing wrong, so I'll supply you with a fresh direction. Note that
$$ \sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$$ 
so the inequality can be written as 
$$ 2 \cos^2(x) + \cos(x) - 1 \geq 0$$
Now if we set $y = \cos(x)$ can you see what form the inequality takes?

Comment: 2cos^x-1+cosx>=0: (2cosx-1)(cosx+1)>=0 : cox=-1 / cosx=1/2/cosx>1/2

Comment: Thank you! I solved it. To those who don't understand it. From $2 \cos^2 x+ \cos x -1 $ now we get $$ (\cos x - \frac{1}{2})(\cos x +1) \geq 0 $$ Knowing that $(\cos x  +1)$ is always greater or equal to 1, we only examine $\cos x -\frac{1}{2}$ when it is greater or equal to zero.

Comment: @Gjekask: I think you mean $\cos x+1$ is always greater than or equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

This amounts to solve the inequality 2cos^2 x+cosx-1>0. Use the discriminant.

Comment: easier way: (2cosx-1)(cosx+1)>=0

Comment: Guys, why are you both doesn't use latex? Is it so hard?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\cos^2x − \sin^2x & \geq −\cos x\\
\cos^2x − \cos^2x-1 & \geq −\cos x\\
2\cos^2x + \cos x + 1 & \geq 0
\end{align*}
solving for cosx
$$\cos x = [-\infty,1] \cup \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$$
rejecting 1st part
$$\cos x \geq \frac{1}{2}$$
$$x \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$x \geq -\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: yeah sorry that one

Comment: Be careful.  $\sin^2x = 1 - \cos^2x$, so $-\sin^2x = -1 + \cos^2x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$0\le\cos x+\cos2x=2\cos\dfrac{3x}2\cos\dfrac x2=2\cos^2\dfrac x2\left(4\cos^2\dfrac x2-3\right)$$

$$\implies0\le4\cos^2\dfrac x2-3=2(1+\cos x)-3=2\cos x-1\iff\cos x\ge\dfrac12$$

$2n\pi-\dfrac\pi3\le x\le2n\pi+\dfrac\pi3$ where $n$ is any integer